# Partial marginalization of conditional probability

Tags: probability

I was reading about marginalization on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution), specifically I read:

$$p_X(x) = \int_y p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)p_Y(y)\,dy$$

I was wondering if the following is true

$$\int_y p_{X\mid YZ}(x\mid y,z)p_Y(y) \, dy = p_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)$$

$X, Y$ and $Z$ are random variables, with pdf-s $p_X$, p$_Y$ and $p_Z$ respectively.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But what if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: The notation $p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ is a criminal abomination.  If should say $p_{X\mid Y=y} (x)$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if ${p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{Y}}(y)={p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{Y\mid Z}}(y\mid z)$

By the Law of Total Probability:

$${p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{X\mid Z}}(x\mid z) =\int_{\Bbb R} {p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{X\mid Y,Z}}(x\mid y,z)~{p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{Y\mid Z}}(y\mid z) \,\mathrm{d}y$$

However *if* $Y$ and $Z$ are pairwise independent, then indeed:
$${p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{X\mid Z}}(x\mid z) =\int_{\Bbb R} {p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{X\mid Y,Z}}(x\mid y,z)~{p}_{\lower{0.5ex}{Y}}(y) \,\mathrm{d}y$$